# Error in consuming sample message from Wso2mb

Tags: wso2, wso2-message-broker

I tried to run wso2mb-3.1.0/samples/JmsMessageListenerClient but I get below error on server start. Am I missing some config?

```
org.wso2.andes.AMQConnectionFailureException: Unable to Connect
            at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection.<init>(AMQConnection.java:475)
            at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(AMQConnectionFactory.java:328)
            at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionFactory.createTopicConnection(AMQConnectionFactory.java:443)
            at com.wickes.common.jms.service.wso2mq.Wso2MessageListener.registerSubscribers(Wso2MessageListener.java:41)
            at com.wickes.product.web.Controller.get(Controller.java:25)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
            at org.wso2.msf4j.internal.router.HttpMethodInfo.invoke(HttpMethodInfo.java:132)
            at org.wso2.msf4j.internal.MSF4JMessageProcessor.dispatchMethod(MSF4JMessageProcessor.java:130)
            at org.wso2.msf4j.internal.MSF4JMessageProcessor.receive(MSF4JMessageProcessor.java:72)
            at org.wso2.carbon.transport.http.netty.listener.WorkerPoolDispatchingSourceHandler.lambda$publishToWorkerPool$12(WorkerPoolDispatchingSourceHandler.java:125)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
javax.jms.JMSException: Error creating connection: Unable to Connect
            at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(AMQConnectionFactory.java:338)
            at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionFactory.createTopicConnection(AMQConnectionFactory.java:443)
            at com.wickes.common.jms.service.wso2mq.Wso2MessageListener.registerSubscribers(Wso2MessageListener.java:41)
            at com.wickes.product.web.Controller.get(Controller.java:25)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
            at org.wso2.msf4j.internal.router.HttpMethodInfo.invoke(HttpMethodInfo.java:132)
            at org.wso2.msf4j.internal.MSF4JMessageProcessor.dispatchMethod(MSF4JMessageProcessor.java:130)
            at org.wso2.msf4j.internal.MSF4JMessageProcessor.receive(MSF4JMessageProcessor.java:72)
            at org.wso2.carbon.transport.http.netty.listener.WorkerPoolDispatchingSourceHandler.lambda$publishToWorkerPool$12(WorkerPoolDispatchingSourceHandler.java:125)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.wso2.andes.AMQConnectionFailureException: Unable to Connect
            at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection.<init>(AMQConnection.java:475)
            at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(AMQConnectionFactory.java:328)
            ... 14 more
```

2017-02-21 16:03 ERROR AMQStateManager:162 - Notifying Waiters([org.wso2.andes.client.state.StateWaiter@520acd8f]) for error:Exception thrown against AMQConnection:
Host: localhost
Port: 5672
Virtual Host: carbon
Client ID: carbon
Active session count: 0: org.wso2.andes.AMQDisconnectedException: Server closed connection and reconnection not permitted.
2017-02-21 16:03 ERROR AMQProtocolHandler:485 - Exception processing frame
org.wso2.andes.framing.AMQProtocolClassException: Protocol class 1 was expected; received 3
            at org.wso2.andes.framing.ProtocolInitiation.checkVersion(ProtocolInitiation.java:190)
            at org.wso2.andes.client.protocol.AMQProtocolHandler$2.run(AMQProtocolHandler.java:476)
            at org.wso2.andes.pool.Job.processAll(Job.java:109)
            at org.wso2.andes.pool.Job.run(Job.java:157)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017-02-21 16:03 ERROR AMQConnection:1307 - Throwable Received but no listener set: org.wso2.andes.AMQDisconnectedException: Server closed connection and reconnection not permitted.
2017-02-21 16:03 ERROR AMQConnection:1307 - Throwable Received but no listener set: org.wso2.andes.framing.AMQProtocolClassException: Protocol class 1 was expected; received 3

Thanks,
Manish

Comment: With a fresh WSO2 MB install it work just fine for me...What changes do you do?

Comment: It resolved now. Actually, I made port offset 3, assuming it will just add 3 in 9443, but it increased the MQ port as well by 3.